# Rotate a Multiple Lines in OpenCV/Python

Tags: python, opencv, math, graphics, drawing

I have many lines in my opencv, I want to rotate them but Opencv does not have shape rotation functionality. It has image rotation function.

I made a rectangle and drew the lines on it. then I rotated it with cv2.getRotationMatrix2D. I tried creating a mask with cv2.addWeighted and adding the lines on the image, but it didn't work properly.

I drew some examples using Canva:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the code I use to draw the lines:

```
def draw_lines(img, color, cx, cy, deg):

    deg = int(deg)

    for a in range(720, -720, -30):

        img = cv2.line(img, (cx-165, cy+a),  (cx+165, cy+a), color, 1,cv2.LINE_AA)
            
    return img
```

How can i rotate these lines using only math?

*info: Bended Lines Example(Not Rotate):
I want to rotate them.

[image: Bended Lines]

Comment: you should calculate the end points of each line, then draw it. the math involves trigonometry. since you're already aware of rotation matrices, you shouldn't have much trouble with that.

Comment: I tried, when I calculate the first and last points with trigonometry, the lines do not rotate, they just bend in the same line. I think it's something more complex.

Comment: Does this example help: https://www.atqed.com/numpy-rotate-vector ?

Comment: This is a good example for 4-point images, but I couldn't apply it to multiple lines written with a for loop.

Comment: I added bended lines example on question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rotation matrix rotates vectors around the origin `(0, 0)`. You always have to consider in which coordinate system the vectors are that you want to rotate.

Putting your code and the example together:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from math import cos, sin


def draw_lines(img, color, cx, cy, deg):
    theta = np.deg2rad(deg)
    rot = np.array([[cos(theta), -sin(theta)], [sin(theta), cos(theta)]])

    c = np.array([cx, cy])

    for a in range(720, -720, -30):
        v1 = np.dot(rot, np.array([-165, a])).astype(int)
        v2 = np.dot(rot, np.array([165, a])).astype(int)

        img = cv2.line(img, c + v1, c + v2, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    return img


def main():
    img = np.zeros((2000, 2000, 3), np.uint8)  # create empty black image
    draw_lines(img, [255, 255, 255], 1000, 1000, 30)
    cv2.imwrite("out.png", img)


main()
```

Comment: it workeddd!! thanks a lot. "np.zeros((2000, 2000, 3), np.uint8)" what exactly does this do?

Comment: makes an array with all 0 in it. details to be found in numpy documentation.

Comment: @HighHill: I use `np.zeros` to create an empty RGB image as canvas.